# Swift 3 Optional Binding for Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsnotificationcenter, swift-protocols

**Edit:** solved, see my solution below. I'm still curious as to why it works, perhaps your solution could explain this?

~

I'm passing an object using a NotificationCenter post notification.

My goal is to optionally unwrap the `notification.object` if it adheres to a certain `protocol`.

The problem is in testing, the unwrap is proving unsuccessful and i'm not sure why.

The series of objects (sometimes an `enum`, sometimes a `struct`) who adhere to a `NotificationsPipelineProtocol` and send those objects along with the notification to the receiving object who subscribes to those notifications.

So for instance if I were passing a ReleaseNote in to the Notifications Pipeline I would have it subscribe to the protocol:

```
enum ReleaseNote: Float, NotificationsPipelineProtocol {
    ...
```

When I want to post to the `NotificationCenter` an extension function written for all items subscribing to the `NotificationsPipelineProtocol` is called:

```
    // finishing task, wants to post completion
    ...
        self.postCompletion()
    ...
```

Calling this function

```
    func postCompletion() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self.completionNotificationName, object: self)
    }
```

Which I have guaranteed to be recieved properly using this function:

```
@objc private func didReceiveNotificationCompletion(_ notification : Notification) {

    guard let completedNotification = notification.object as? NotificationsPipelineProtocol else {
        return
    }
```

But the above guard statement does not unwrap and bind the optional because `return` is executed.

I have printed `notification.object` to console and also guarantee that it is in fact receiving the intended object.

Might you have any idea why it won't unwrap?

Comment: Isn't it arriving in .object wrapped in NSValue or an NSNumber? Check the property class in runtime.

Comment: I'm given the result: '_SwiftValue' when I print to console

Comment: Might it be that I need to bridge it to some sort of NSObject protocol? granted that the NotificationCenter is bridged to Objective-C?

Comment: Quick idea - try `notification.object as Any as? NotificationsPipelineProtocol`

Comment: It didn't work. It's a good try, but I believe it already is received as an Any? so casting it to Any seems redundant

Comment: solved, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by replacing access to the pipeline object from object to userInfo.

I'm not entirely sure why this is the way it should be, but it does work.

Posting the object

```
    func postCompletion() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self.completionNotificationName, object: nil, userInfo: ["pipelineItem": self])
    }
```

Retrieving the object

```
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
          let completedNotification = userInfo["pipelineItem"] as? NotificationsPipelineProtocol else {
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issue with this workflow, maybe you're observing / sending the wrong object?

Here's an example of what you're trying to do that you can use in a playground to see that it works. Try moving your code into a playground / example project in it's simplest case until you find the failure point!

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

protocol NotificationsPipelineProtocol {

}

class TestObserver: NotificationsPipelineProtocol {

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(notificationFired(_:)),
                                               name: nil,
                                               object: self)
    }

    dynamic func notificationFired(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let object = notification.object as? NotificationsPipelineProtocol else {
            return
        }

        print("success")
    }

    func fireNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "test"), object: self)
    }

}

let observer = TestObserver()
observer.fireNotification()
```

Comment: I agree, there shouldn't be. But this is.. I'll consider trying out your code in a sandbox but what you see above is what is in written in code so I can't imagine it'll be much different of results